# spark.conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", '6g') is not updating the default value - PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to update the spark.driver.maxResultSize value to 6g but the value is not getting update.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", '6g')
```

Note: I am running this command in Azure Databricks Notebook.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In **Spark 2.0+** you should be able to use `SparkSession.conf.set` method to set some configuration option at runtime but it's mostly limited to SQL configuration. Since you're trying to update the `conf` of `spark.driver`, you need to `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate` new session with your new `conf` (if you have one running). Such as:

```py
import pyspark

sc = spark.sparkContext
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([("spark.driver.maxResultSize", '6g')])

# here you stop the old spark context with old conf
sc.stop()
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Alternatively, you can just `getOrCreate` new session with predefined config, e.g. from a YAML file or from code. You can then check the new conf yourself using

```py
sc.getConf().getAll()
```

Comment: As you tagged that you are using Databricks, you can check which options are configurable at runtime using the command
`spark.conf.isModifiable("spark.driver.maxResultSize")` which will tell you that this driver command is not configurable at runtime and thus you need to use the session creation aspects that @Napoleon mentions above to apply this to a new session.

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect declaration of values in single quotas it should be double quotes.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", '6g')
```

Please do change it to:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "6g")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to see the current max size of your driver

```
sqlContext.getConf("spark.driver.maxResultSize")
```

It gives the current max size of storage capacity as 20 GB

Now, to increase : To increase the maxResultSize you can use the above command.

But it is not recommended to increase beyond your driver capacity

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.driver.maxResultSize","30g")
```